# EC2-generated key ssh setup OSX

Tags: macos, ssh

Here's the situation:

- I generated and downloaded an ssh key as a .pem file using the EC2 console
- I gave this key to my colleague with a PC and he has been able to log to the server with it just fine using PuTTY.
- I have been trying for hours to figure out where to put the .pem file such that I can call

  ssh -v [SERVER IP ADDRESS] -l [USERNAME]

I know that the IP address and the username are accurate because that's what my colleague is using. Where do I put the .pem file, and what permissions do I set? It seems that every tutorial on this stuff assumes you generated the key using ssh-keygen, which apparently handles all this for you, and the directions on EC2 don't tell you what to do beyond downloading the key.

My current setup is this:

- I copied the text inside the .pem file and put it in ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- I set the permissions to chmod 600 id_rsa
- I'm geting a massive error that ends with the line "Permission denied (publickey)"

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use ssh -i keyfile.pem user@host.com. This will use the identity file (.pem that EC2 gave you)